# I'm having some problems with a query, I have a nested document

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nested

```
"query":{
"nested": {
  "path":  "lang",
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "lang.name", 
      "query": "*Bat*"
    
    }
   }
  }
}
```

It is working but I want to search also in `product_model` (it's nested path like). How can I merge the two queries ? Thank you.

```
 "query":{
"nested": {
  "path":  "product_model",
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "product_model.keyword", 
      "query": "*Bat*"
    
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

If you want to filter documents based on value either in product_model or lang then use should clause(OR)

If you want to filter documents based on value in both product_model and lang then use must clause(AND)

**Should example**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "lang",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "lang.name",
                "query": "*Bat*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "product_model",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "product_model.name",
                "query": "*Bat*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Must example**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "lang",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "lang.name",
                "query": "*Bat*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "product_model",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "product_model.name",
                "query": "*Bat*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```